# How do I find the path delimiter character in .NET?

Tags: .net

Is there some built-in constant for the path delimiter (i.e. \ vs /)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

System.IO.Path has two readonly fields for this purpose:

- [Path.DirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx): contains '\' on Windows, '/' on UNIX
- [Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar.aspx): contains '/' on Windows, '\' on UNIX

Then there are two additional fields for the volume separator and path separator:

- [Path.VolumeSeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.volumeseparatorchar.aspx): the character used to separate the volume name/drive letter from the rest of tha path (':' on windows, '/' on UNIX)
- [Path.PathSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.pathseparator.aspx): the character used to separate multiple paths (';')

Comment: What about japanese systems? They use ¥ as path directory seperator. Is this also included in `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`?

Comment: @Sunburst275: no, This is a case of awkward behavior: on windows the separator is actually the byte `0x5C`. In the ANSI and Unicode encodings this would be a backslash but in Shift-JIS encoding for Japanese locales this is a `¥` character. This means that low-level file system operations will need to do something weird to avoid encoding DirectorySeparatorChar with the environmental Encoding, but I'm not sure where exactly that happens.

Comment: Thank you! I always wondered why that is the case. So do japanese file systems also support the backslash, or how should I write my code to also make it compatible with JP systems?

Comment: Is this really an operating system behavior, and not a filesystem behavior?

Answer (score 13):

System.IO.Path has these sort of information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx